# How do i decode the output of /proc/$$/statm?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I am trying to understand the output given by statm. This is part of task to analyze memory usage of a process which keeps bothering the system performance.From few blogs i got to know "statm" is the simplified version of "smaps",but not sure how to read this.

Sample output:

```
myhost:/proc/64498 $ cat statm
30217 855 752 213 0 126 0
```

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at the Kernel's [Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt):

```
Table 1-3: Contents of the statm files (as of 2.6.8-rc3)
..............................................................................
 Field    Content
 size     total program size (pages)        (same as VmSize in status)
 resident size of memory portions (pages)   (same as VmRSS in status)
 shared   number of pages that are shared   (i.e. backed by a file, same
                                             as RssFile+RssShmem in status)
 trs      number of pages that are 'code'   (not including libs; broken,
                                             includes data segment)
 lrs      number of pages of library        (always 0 on 2.6)
 drs      number of pages of data/stack     (including libs; broken,
                                             includes library text)
 dt       number of dirty pages             (always 0 on 2.6)
```